# Upload File in Angular through an API which accepts File as Blob and requires Multi part Form Data

Tags: javascript, angular, multipartform-data, angular10

I am building a form in angular which is used to upload a file and I have a third party API that I need to call which accepts Multi part form data and file as blob. Can you please tell me how can I do that? I have this code for now?

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="customerFileGroup" (submit)="submit($event)">
  <div>
      <input
        formControlName="file"
        type="file"
        accept=".csv,text/plain, text/csv, text/html"
        (onSelection)="changeFile($event)"
      />
  </div>
<button>Submit</button  

</form>
```

Typescript

```
export class CustomerFile{
  constructor(private readonly _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  const customerFileGroup: FormGroup = this._fb.group({
      file: this._fb.control(null),
    });


  submit(e: Event): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileUploadGroup.value);
    // this.customerFileService.uploadFile(formData.file?);
    What should I send here because the API requires file as blob now

  }
```

File/API

```
public uploadFile(
    file: Blob
  )
{
 // Black box for me

}
```

Swagger

[image]

I am trying to understand what do I need to pass in the service so it is multi part form data but the request body of file is a blob. I am using Angular 10. Let me know if more info is required

If I pass the formdata, I get the following error:

Argument of type 'FormData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ngModel` or `formControl` to get file, you have to store the file in variable manually when file changes, see the example below

```html
<form [formGroup]="customerFileGroup" (submit)="submit($event)">
  <div>
    <input
      formControlName="file"
      type="file"
      accept=".csv,text/plain, text/csv, text/html"
      (change)="changeFile($event)" <!-- Change event name to "change" -->
    />
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
export class CustomerFile{
...
 fileToUpload: FileList;

 changeFile(evt) {
    this.fileToUpload = evt.target.files[0];
 }

 submit(e: Event): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload);
    this.customerFileService.uploadFile(formData);
 }
}
```

```js
export class CustomerFileService {

 ...

   public uploadFile(payload: FormData) {
    return this.http.post('<API_URL>',payload);
   }

}
```

Comment: You are passing formData to the service but the service accepts file as a blob. I am confused from swagger and the service method. Is the file here a blob?

Comment: Multipart is passed as formdata from front-end, try the code and let me know

Comment: It complains because it says "Argument of type 'FormData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'"

Comment: Can you add that in question, where exactly you are getting the error?

Comment: Added. The error is that when I try to pass formData to the service, it complains because service is expecting a blob

Comment: Please add your service code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245367/discussion-between-learn-aspnet-and-sameer).

Comment: Hey, it is in the question which is a black box

public uploadFile(
file: Blob
)
{
// Black Box
}

Comment: Updated the answer, You need to change the argument type from `Blob` to `FormData` since that's what getting passed